# Flask-Mobility でスマホ表示をPCで表示する方法はありませんか？

Tags: python

Flask-Mobility を使っているのですが、PCのブラウザでスマホ表示の確認をする方法はないでしょうか？スマホかPCかの判定をライブラリ内で行っていると思うので、それを外部から制御できるとよいと思うのですが

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask-Mobilityの[ソース](https://github.com/rehandalal/flask-mobility/blob/master/flask_mobility/main.py#L15)を見ると、User-Agentヘッダをみてモバイルかどうかを判断しています。

ほとんどのブラウザに、カスタムのUser-Agentヘッダを送る機能があると思いますので、それを使ってモバイルブラウザのUser-Agentを送るようにすれば、スマホ版の表示を確認できると思います。

iPhoneのUser-Agentの例

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
```

Google Chromeでは、開発者ツールの左上にあるスマホアイコンをクリックすることでモバイルをはじめとしたデバイスの[エミュレーションモードを起動](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#enable-device-mode)できます。

Answer (score 1):

リクエスト前処理の "before_request" で "request.MOBILE = True" とする事で表示をスマホ版に強制的に切り替える事が可能です。

```
@public.before_request
def before_request():
    request.MOBILE = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Chromeだと、F12で表示できるデベロッパーツールから画面サイズの固定やUser-Agentのオーバーライドができます。

### 方法

1. F12を押す
2. デベロッパーツール左上の虫眼鏡の右隣にあるスマホのアイコンをクリック
3. `Device`欄から既存のスマホのプロファイルを選ぶ
4. (再現したいスマホがない場合は) 画面サイズ・通信帯域・User-Agent(`UA`欄)を入力
5. F5で更新し反映